# Run FXCopAnalyzer only for debug build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using the [FxCopAnalyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers) for an advanced static code analysis in a C# project. This project is configured to treat warnings as errors in the release build but not for debug:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This is now causing problems (because the static code analysis warnings are errors) for a release build if the FxCopAnalyzer is running with the build. So I decided to include the package reference only for the debug build like this:

```
   <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.12" >
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This works fine if I do a clean build for debug and then a clean build for release. Working fine in this scenario means I get the static code analysis warnings (as warnings) in the debug build and I get no static code analysis warnings (so no errors) in the release build.

The problem occurs if I do e.g. a debug build first and then a release build. In this case the release build (somehow) includes also the FxCopAnalyzer and creates warnings for static code analysis and therefore I have errors in the build.

What I want to achieve is to have the static code analysis running but the warnings should not be treated as errors for release BUT the default warnings MUST be treated as errors. It is ok if the static code analysis is only running for debug and not for release. Any ideas?

Comment: The workflow doesn't make much sense.  As-is, you can't start testing and debugging the code until all warnings are fixed.  You don't build Release until it is tested.  Which of course implies that the Release build won't generate any warnings.  FxCop is deprecated and no longer maintained, do move to the Roslyn analyzers.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok so I will start now fixing several of thousands warnings in a big legacy project before I can deploy any build. "You don't build Release until it is tested"? Also what should that mean, how can I "test" code which I cannot build. I want to have an overview on how many warnings are left in the project and track this over time to reduce the number of warnings (what we already do by gated check-ins on DevOps). I simply cannot REMOVE all SCA-warnings at once. Every other warning is already removed

Comment: FxCopAnalyzers has been deprecated and no longer maintained. This page can provide some reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/migrate-from-fxcop-analyzers-to-net-analyzers?view=vs-2019